# Unable to enable Caching in rebing/graphql-laravel

Tags: laravel, caching, graphql

I'm using the rebing/graphql-laravel package in my Laravel application to handle GraphQL queries. I have configured Automatic Persisted Queries (APQ) to cache the keys using Redis as the cache driver. However, I'm facing an issue where the keys are not being cached as expected.

In my config/graphql.php file, I have the following APQ configuration:

```
'apq' => [
    'enable' => env('GRAPHQL_APQ_ENABLE', false),
    'cache_driver' => env('GRAPHQL_APQ_CACHE_DRIVER', config('cache.default')),
    'cache_prefix' => config('cache.prefix') . ':graphql.apq',
    'cache_ttl' => 300,
],
```

I have also set the cache driver to Redis in my .env file with the following configuration:

```
GRAPHQL_APQ_ENABLE=true
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
```

According to these settings, the Laravel GraphQL library should cache all queries in the Redis cache database with the prefix laravel_cache:graphql.apq. However, after setting up and running artisan config:cache, I checked both the main database (DB 0) and the cache database (DB 1) in Redis but couldn't find any keys with the laravel_cache:graphql.apq prefix. I confirmed this by running the following command inside the Redis database:

```
keys laravel_cache:graphql.apq*
```

I have also reviewed the cache configuration in config/cache.php to ensure the Redis cache store is properly defined.

Could you please assist me in resolving this issue? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.